# Passing ModelForm in URLConfig Django

Tags: django

I want to send model form object in the URLConf just like this

```
 url('^myUrl/Url/$',
'myView',
 {"EvaluationForm": MyModelForm()},
```

when i try to get this form in the view like this.

```
myView(request, EvaluationForm=None):
form = EvaluationForm(request.POST)
```

i get the following error.

`'MarketExpertEvaluationForm' object is not callable`

Can anybody tell me whats the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: any reason to pass form class in the url why cant you use it in the view itself?

Comment: the reason is, i had three views (viw1, viw2, viw3) they were all doing the same thing,
getting the data from post and saving it. i have override the form.save method to all the functionality. 
by passing the form argument in the view, i am able to write 3 lines for URL(3 different) but they all redirect on one view...

that helped me reducing my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating and passing instance, try to pass class object in url as

```
url('^myUrl/Url/$',
   'myView',
    {"EvaluationForm": MyModelForm}, #<-- note no ()
```